# Click Not working on first attempt inside Vertical Scroll jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am using HorizontalPager introduced in jetpack compose. But i am facing some interesting issue. To reporduce exact issue i am using only One Tab in my HorizontalPager having a scroll. In My tab at bottom i have added a button with click listener but that click listener do not work until i press 3-4 times when user scroll down.

Here is my code.

```
 @OptIn(ExperimentalPagerApi::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {

            val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = 1)
            val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

            HorizontalPager(state = pagerState) { page ->

                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .verticalScroll(scrollState)
                        .fillMaxSize()
                ) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .height(1000.dp), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                    ) {
                        Text(text = "Box")
                    }

                    Button(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        onClick = { showToastMsg("Hello") }) {
                        Text(text = "Button")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Can any one help please guide what i am doing wrong ??

Comment: This is still a problem in Jetpack Compose 1.4.0 Foundation Pagers.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code based on your code and it seems to be working correctly for me:

```
    setContent {
            Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                val pagerState = rememberPagerState(1)
                val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

                HorizontalPager(state = pagerState, pageCount = 3) { page ->

                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .verticalScroll(scrollState)
                            .fillMaxSize()
                    ) {
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxSize()
                                .height(1000.dp), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                        ) {
                            Text(text = "Box")
                        }

                        Button(
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                            onClick = {
                                Log.d("Hello",  "page : $page")
                            }
                        ) {
                            Text(text = "Button")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm using the latest version of accompanist (0.29.1-alpha). So the issue is either in your version of accompanist. Or it could be your `showToastMsg` method where the issue is.

Comment: Thanks @Talha Mir I have updated to  accompanist (0.29.1-alpha). Its working now. Thanks